# Accordion menus & innerHTML

Tags: ajax, accordion, innerhtml

I've been using a shareware JS accordion-style sidebar (www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/slashdot.htm). It's been working beautifully with PHP-based HTML, but is not working with AJAX.

The sidebar builds itself on `<div>`,`<span>`and`<a>` elements. Here is a section of the JS code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.submenus.length; i++)
    this.submenus[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].onclick = function() {
        mainInstance.toggleMenu(this.parentNode);
    };
```

If I use hardcoded HTML like the following (or construct the same with PHP), it works fine:

```
<div id="navbar_side" class="sdmenu">
<div><span>STUDENTS</span><a>Adding Students</a><a>Deleting Students</a></div>
</div>
```

However, if I start with:

```
<div id="navbar_side" class="sdmenu"></div>
```

and then use this:

```
document.getElementById("navbar_side").innerHTML="<div><span>STUDENTS</span><a>Adding Students</a><a>Deleting Students</a></div>";
```

the menu doesn't slide. The info is all there. The `<a hrefs>` all work (which I've left out here). But the accordion movement doesn't - well... - move!

Why is this? Clearly the menu is not reading the AJAX-constructed node tree the same way as the PHP-constructed one.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Actually jQuery UI offers a nice Accordion widget for free. Nice & AJAX ready.

Comment: Yes, I've pondered the jQuery one since this stopped working. But if I can just get it to work again, I'd be very happy!

Comment: Are the doc-types are same in both the cases?

Comment: Yes, Kangkan. Everything is identical except for the method by which the contents of <div id="navbar_side"...> are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend you to start over your work by using [jQuery UI - Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). Much cleaner & effective.

Comment: Yes, I've pondered the jQuery one since this stopped working. But if I can just get it to work again, I'd be very happy!